# gem5:``` /usr/bin/scons: No such file or directory```

Tags: bash, software-installation, scons

So I installed gem5 according to documentation : https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/building

There is an example to run : `scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j 4`
When I tried that I got this **error** :  `bash: /usr/bin/scons: No such file or directory`.

When I am in gem5 directory if I type `ls` I can see these files: [image]
Do you know what's the problem ?

Comment: Hello. Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? When you ran the suggested `sudo apt install ...` command from the "Setup" instructions did it complete successfully, without any errors?

Comment: @steeldriver ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @steeldriver I think it did not report something, I tried to re-run ```sudo apt``` . There is no implicit error report, only packages that were installed